# Azure Devops api get retained builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to use Azure Devops rest apis to get all retained builds of a specific build definition.

Reading [Azure Devops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) I tried this api:

> https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions=1

With this I get all build of my build definition '1'.

Each build has the 'keepForever' property. If this has value 'true', that is a retained build.

Usually the retained builds are fewer than non retained.
I'd want to have just the retained ones.

I tried to add the 'keepForever=true' query string parameter with no luck.

Is there a way to made the http request to get retained builds only?

Can I avoid to read much data I don't want?

Comment: This is old, but I came across it before I found another question that provided what I was looking for, so I'm posting a link to it here in case anyone else has the same experience. In [How can I delete an Azure DevOps build definition that it claims is retained by a release?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885522/1445598) the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889636/1445598) has a PowerShell script that uses the Azure DevOps REST API and filtering to get the list of builds that are retained by a release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of parameters here: [Builds - List - URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#uri-parameters). There is no `keepForever` in that list and no any additional filter options for this parameter. As workaround, you may try to set some tag for retained builds and then use `tagFilters` parameter. But that maybe more complex way than filter `keepForever` property with your code.